# Git workflow involving a local repository and 2 remote repositories: staging and production repositories on the same server

Tags: git, workflow, git-remote, git-bare

I have read a few Stack Overflow threads about this, but many of them did not seem to answer the question that I was asking, or at least there were different conditions that didn't seem applicable to mine.

How can I set up the following?

Local Repository:

- Always fetch / pull from, let's say `live.git`, a remote `bare repo`, which should be the latest stable version of a git-maintained site. The pull would merge into the master branch of the local repo. Any local development would then be done on the development branch, and merged into the local master when done, then pushed to the development branch of the remote Staging repo.

Remote Repository:

- Testing/Staging: A non-bare git repository, which has two branches: master and development. From above, any locally pushed commits would be merged into the development branch of the remote Staging repo. If the Staging environment has been tested and reviewed, I'd merge the Staging development branch into the Staging master branch. I'd then push the master branch (the actual push post-receive / update would only work if I was on the master branch on Staging) to the `bare repo` which would have either a `post-receive` or a `post-update` hook defined to checkout to the live directory on the server.

My thinking is that testing could be done on staging non-bare repo, and pushes can be made to live bare repo when everyone seems fine. If anything is wrong, then I could rollback by checking out the previous commit on staging then pushing it back up to live bare repo.

Note, if it matters: My staging and live site is at the document root, with the former being served as a subdomain (staging..*.com), and the latter at the site root (www..*.com).

I have not been able to get this to work. I am under the assumption that you could have a non-bare repo (staging), have, as its remote, a bare repo (live) on the same server. The local's remote would be staging. *Is a setup like this possible, and, if not, could someone recommend a simple alternate or congruous way?*

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need special repositories for any of that.  Each repository, whether bare or not, offers all those features, as branches.  You'd have branches for each feature that you descibe: development, staging-development, staging and production.

Then rather than "pushing" to a remote, you'd be merging between branches.  Add business rules like

- "junior developers may commit only to development branch",
- "senior developers may commit to development or staging-development, and may merge to staging",
- and "release engineers may merge to production".

You can set up your central repository as a bare repository, and everywhere else gets non-bare repos.  Your test environments use either staging-development or staging branches, and your production machine uses production branch.  Don't merge in a staging or production environemnt; merge on a developer's machine and push to the central repo.  Then you can pull to the staging or po